# Is there any way how to reload all FutureBuilders?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way how to reload all FutureBuilders in application without need to change every futurebuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just call `setState((){})` in the tree (or subtree) that has all the `FutureBuilders` and make sure that the `future` property calls the future method directly, for example. The build method should trigger a new call to the future.